# How to troubleshoot Ubuntu 20.04 with two USB monitors slow display response

Tags: 20.04, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi, freeze

I have a CyberPowerPC Gaming Desktop - AMD Ryzen 7 3700X - AMD Radeon RX 580 is all I know about it. Also a j5Create USB hub I got from BestBuy. Dell 27" monitor, HP 27es monitor. Used to have Ubuntu 18.04 on it. No problems using two USB monitors. Re-installed Ubuntu 20.04. With one monitor connected to HDMI, and 2nd to USB hub, downloaded, extracted, ran "displaylink-driver-5.4.0-55.153.run" to get 2nd monitor to work. So far so good. If I move 1st monitor from HDMI to USB hub (now 2 monitors on USB), the mouse still move just fine across screens, but moving a browser or terminal window, or typing, is veeerry slow - delayed; freeze every couple of seconds.  If I remove one monitor and put it back to HDMI, works fine again.

How could I start to troubleshoot this?

UPDATE: if I remove the HDMI monitor connection and only have the single USB connected monitor, same issue.  So I believe it's same issue as others who close their laptop lid with a single USB monitor connected.

Comment: Why did you download and run this file?  Was there a preexisting problem?  Where did you obtain the file?

Comment: hi, prior to running "displaylink-driver-5.4.0-55.153.run", only the HDMI monitor displayed. No USB-connected monitors even displayed (just black screen - no input received).  Once ran, as long as I have an HDMI monitor connected, then the USB-connected monitor works fine.